# Safari fixed/absolute relative to bottom-right

Tags: css, safari

Here is the CSS for my wrapper and my h3

```
#introWrap {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#introWrap h3 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 200px);
    left: calc(100% - 800px);
}
```

On Chrome/Firefox the `h3` appears at the correct position (bottom-right). On Safari for some reason he doesn't understand that CSS and defaults to top-left (0 - 0).

I have tried every combination of positions fixed/absolute, I tried using `vh` and `vw` instead of %. Can't seem to force Safari to position `h3` correctly.

You can see it in action [here](http://rlcoaching.com/albaraka/) (h3 is the bigger text in the "intro", you'll notice it appears bottom right on all browsers except Safari)

EDIT: In response to one of the comments here is the HTML:

```
<section id="introWrap">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    </div>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <h4>Title</h4>
</section>
```

I don't think it's entirely relevant to the problem though. h1 h2 and h4 are not positioned relative to the 100% document height/width so they appear juste fine. Positioning h3 to the bottom right though just doesn't work this way in Safari.

Comment: Please give us some HTML code to work with as well.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Uploaded some! Hope it helps, please tell me if you need any other info, this problem is driving me nuts. I can't for the life of me understand why it's not working on Safari. Also there's a link to the page, perhaps that can help see visually what's going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that

```
top: calc(100% - 200px);
left: calc(100% - 800px);
```

is the same as

```
bottom:0;
right:0;
```

So - [**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwbEn/) - Tested in Safari 5, W7 64bit + Chrome etc,

Comment: Safari does not seem to support `calc` at this time.

Comment: I found that `bottom: 0` works if you zero out the bottom margin of the `h3` element.

Comment: It should [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/calc) but then [CanIUee 2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in Safari/Webkit such that `calc` does not deal with the viewport units correctly, which I think is probably related to what is happening here, because if viewport units are not working correctly, webkit may have trouble determining the viewport height.